# Flex item not filling screen height with "align-items: stretch"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

With `body`'s `flex-direction: row;`, I am expecting its `align-items: stretch;` will stretch the child item vertically to fill the screen height. I don't understand why this is not happening.

Here's a minimal example of what I am trying to do. I am expecting the blue block to fill the entire green body.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  background-color: green;
}
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flexContainer">
    Hello
  </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qc6fu1b3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not happening because the height of `body` is the height of the content.

See the red border around `body` in your code: https://jsfiddle.net/qc6fu1b3/2/

As you can see, `align-items: stretch` has no space to work.

Unlike width, which block elements fill 100% by default, heights must be defined. Otherwise, elements default to `auto` – the height of the content.

When you say:

> I am expecting [...] the child item vertically to fill the screen height.

There's no reason to expect this with CSS default behavior. If you want the element to expand the height of the screen, then define that in your code:

```css
html { height: 100%; }

body {
       height: 100%;
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       align-items: stretch;
       align-content: stretch;
       background-color: green;
}

.flexContainer {
      display: flex;
      background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="flexContainer">Hello</div>
</body>
```