# Why flex items are not stretching with align items and with align content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**First Edit:** if i use `align-items: stretch;` I am able to stretch my flex items, I don't know what to make of it, but I was playing around with it, and thought I should add this info as edit as well, `align-items: stretch` value, stretching the flex items.

**Second edit :** Ok may be i am not clear, i am not looking for solution, i just want to know why it's not streching with justify-content, that's it, i can solve this problem my self, by editing the code, but i want to know the reason, why it is acting the way its acting.

I already read this answer [Flex item not filling screen height with "align-items: stretch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213092/flex-item-not-filling-screen-height-with-align-items-stretch)

But my problem is different, as soon as I add `align-items`, flex-items stop stretching, before adding this property they work fine, I know I can solve this problem by adding height to `100%`, but I am not interested in that, I want to know why it's behaving this way.
**Note:** I am using chrome

**My code please read the comment, in the code**

```css
.container {
  font-size: 36px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  /* as soon as i add this align-items property or my items 
  stop streching, i don't get it, if use value stretch it streches 
  the my items, please read the note first edit in the question, 
  it is at the top */
  align-content: stretch;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  color: #fff;
}

.box1 {
  background: blue;
}

.box2 {
  background: red
}

.box3 {
  background: yellow
}

.box4 {
  background: black
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">Home</div>
  <div class="box box2">Menu</div>
  <div class="box box3">About Us</div>
  <div class="box box4">Contact Us</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `box` items can't both `stretch` and `center` at the same time.

Combining `align-items` and `align-content` won't make that happen as `align-items` applies on flex items on a single row and `align-content` when they wrap.

*Note, you don't need to add `align-items/content` and set their value to `stretch`, it is their default*

---

As for a solution, setting the `box` to `height: 100%` will make them *look stretched*, though will give a completely different result compared to make use of the *align-items/content's* `stretch` value.

With a fixed height they will be that set height, no matter if there will be 2 or more rows, with `stretch` whey will adjust their height to fit their parent. Simply put, 2 rows will make them 50% high, 3 rows 33.33% high and so on.

---

Assuming it is the *text* in the `box` you want centered, along with the `box` to stretch, simply make the `box` a flex container too.

Add `display: flex; align-items: center` to the `box` and it likely will layout the way you want.

*If you want the text to also center horizontally, I here added `justify-content: center;`, which you can either keep or remove.*

```css
.container {
  font-size: 36px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;             /*  vertically center    */
  justify-content: center;         /*  horizontally center  */
}

.box1 {
  background: blue;
}

.box2 {
  background: red
}

.box3 {
  background: yellow
}

.box4 {
  background: black
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">Home</div>
  <div class="box box2">Menu</div>
  <div class="box box3">About Us</div>
  <div class="box box4">Contact Us</div>
</div>
```

Comment: beautiful, no i was looking for any particular out put, i was just confused about the out put which i was getting, i spend 3-4 reading mozilla and w3c, and kept on reading again and again, as i was thinking i am missing some thing, you take me out of my misery in four beautiful line, for me you are better than w3c, thanks for taking the time to answer me,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `stretch` value for `align-items` property if you want to stretch the items, not `center` value. So if you just change `align-items:center;` to `align-items:stretch;` it will solve your problem.

https://codepen.io/julysfx/pen/weVvpp

Comment: Thanks for the help, but please read what i wrote at the top of my question, heading first edit, i mentioned my self i can solve it by doing what you just told, but i want to know why i have to ?? that is the question, thanks for help, please read again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are trying to align the boxes to the center and stretch?  You should try adding justify-content:center to the .container:

```
     justify-content: center;
```

Working pen with markup and css you added: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRxyVG

align-items will align your boxes up along the cross axis, whereas justify-content will align them along the main axis.

align-content is more like adjusting the rows or columns in relation to the flex container.  The vertical direction if flex-direction is row, and horizontal if flex-direction is column.  Using align-items is adjusting the row's items on the main axis, you might be able to see how they interact a little better if you make the content random sizes: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weVBBE

When you're setting align-items:center; you're telling the items to align to the center, and they aren't going to stretch.

If you're trying to get the text in the middle of the boxes and have them stretch, you need to apply that to the children ie .box of the .container:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLwEGW

Comment: ok i think i am not clear enough, i want to know why it's acting the way it's acting, sorry thanks for the help

Comment: I updated the answer with some more examples that might help explain it better.

Comment: sorry i knew if i apply direct style to me flex items, i will be able to stretch them, as i mentioned in my question that with height 100%, i can do that, but i did not want that, i want the explaination for the out put i am getting, Thanks for the help, look above i got the answer, and thanks for answering me

Answer (score 0):

Remove height and width from your code. If you want to use the stretch value in the align-items property of display flex you must need to assure that you had not given pre-defined value. In that case it will neglect the values given in align items and run the code.

Answer (score 0):

add `flex-grow` to the columns, they will auto stretch.
Dont include a height or a width.